# How to solve ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\package.json' with ngx-build-plus in workspace with multiple projects?

Tags: angular, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

In my workspace described below, I fail to build project/plugins' that doesn't have package.json with [ngx-build-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-build-plus). If I change back to default builder it works perfectly ok. Workspace has following structure (most items omitted for clarity):

```
- projects
  - shared
    - src 
      - lib
        ...
    - package.json
      ...   
      
  - plugins
    - src
      - app
        ... plugin app is here
    - webpack.config.js  
- src
  - app
  
  ... the main app is here
  
  -webpack.config.js          
-angular.json
-package.json
```

I am trying to implement angular webpack-5 module federation and I'm following example:

https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-plugin-architecture-with-module-federation

In the example the projects/plugins doesn't have own package.json and building it with command **ng build plugins --prod** works without any problem.

I've imitated the example's structure with my existing app that did not have projects folder before. Building the main app is not a problem. Also building shared-library works. However trying to build plugins produces:

```
    'node-sass' usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version. To opt-out of the deprecated behaviour and start using 'sass' uninstall 'node-sass'.
- Generating browser application bundles...Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling shared : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\package.json'
See "C:\Users\char-m\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-plu2me\angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! NIS@0.0.0 build:plugins: `ng build plugins --prod`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the NIS@0.0.0 build:plugins script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\char-m\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-07T19_34_04_884Z-debug.log
```

Clicking '\package.json' in terminal output above opens the package.json in workspace root without a problem.

Copying the package.json from the root to projects/plugins/ solves this issue. However I don't want to duplicate the file.

**EDIT: If I update angular version to older (from 11.1.1) like this:**

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.7
Node: 14.15.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.0.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... material, material-moment-adapter, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.7
@angular/cli                    11.0.7
@angular/language-service       11.2.9
@schematics/angular             11.0.7
@schematics/update              0.1100.7
ng-packagr                      11.2.4
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      4.0.7
webpack                         5.31.0
```

the build works. However this is not an option because this produces [another bug when serving the application](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19550).

Any ideas how to fix this would be highly appreciated.

File angular-errors.log looks like below:

```
[error] HookWebpackError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\package.json'
    at makeWebpackError (C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:49:9)
    at C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:2394:12
    at eval (eval at create (C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:1)
    at fn (C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:376:17)
    at _next4 (eval at create (C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:28:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:47:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
-- inner error --
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\package.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)
    at CacheBackend.provideSync (C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:233:32)
    at WebpackFileSystem.readFileAsUtf8 (C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackFileSystem.js:52:24)
    at PluginChunkReadHandler.getPackageJson (C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:35:43)
    at PluginChunkReadHandler.processModule (C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:45:40)
    at C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:29:23
    at WebpackModuleFileIterator.internalCallback (C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackModuleFileIterator.js:28:13)
    at WebpackModuleFileIterator.iterateFiles (C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackModuleFileIterator.js:8:9)
    at C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:27:32
```

File 2021-04-07T19_34_04_884Z-debug.log looks like this:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build:plugins'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild:plugins', 'build:plugins', 'postbuild:plugins' ]
5 info lifecycle NIS@0.0.0~prebuild:plugins: NIS@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle NIS@0.0.0~build:plugins: NIS@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle NIS@0.0.0~build:plugins: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle NIS@0.0.0~build:plugins: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\char-m\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\char-m\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\char-m\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\char-m\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\char-m\.dotnet\tools
9 verbose lifecycle NIS@0.0.0~build:plugins: CWD: C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp
10 silly lifecycle NIS@0.0.0~build:plugins: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng build plugins --prod' ]
11 info lifecycle NIS@0.0.0~build:plugins: Failed to exec build:plugins script
12 verbose stack Error: NIS@0.0.0 build:plugins: `ng build plugins --prod`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
13 verbose pkgid NIS@0.0.0
14 verbose cwd C:\dev\nis\NIS\ClientApp
15 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
16 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build:plugins"
17 verbose node v14.15.1
18 verbose npm  v6.14.8
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error syscall spawn
21 error file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error NIS@0.0.0 build:plugins: `ng build plugins --prod`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the NIS@0.0.0 build:plugins script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using NX workspace and I was also facing the same issue. I could manage to fix this problem after looking into webpack docs.

What i did i used **--no-extract-licenses** at the end of build command and that worked perfectly.

**Before**: nx build yourAppName --prod

**After**: nx build yourAppName --prod --no-extract-licenses

Hope this works for you too...

Answer (score 0):

I was using nx monorepo and the issue was I had delete the app folder but didn't remove the entry from the `angular.json` file.

You might want to try that if the above doesn't work for you.